# Vim 8 и файлы в русской кодировке

Tags: vi

Коллеги

Обнаружилось следующая проблема, новый vim (версия 8 и только консольное приложение) не желает читать файлы в русской кодировке. А так же выдаёт нечитаемые сообщения об ошибках (в русской кодировке). Каким образом можно побороть эту беду. При этом gvim работает корректно с русскими файлами и выдаёт читаемые сообщения об ошибках. 
На старой версии 7.3 подобной проблемы не наблюдалось

Заранее спасибо
Александр

Comment: русской кодировки нет. есть utf-8, cp1251, кои. И какая ось?

Comment: Windows 7 64-bits

Comment: скорее всего консольный вим запускатся с 866 кодировкой. А текст у Вас в cp1251. Скорее всего поможет "set fileencoding=cp1251"